# How can I store the count of clicking the submit button in browser

Tags: javascript

When click button click count increments and display count but when window or browser close the incremented value are are same and display it when open window after

Comment: could you please provide code sample?

Comment: You can use local storage for this purpose, refer this https://aslamanver.github.io/cricket-score-board/ and https://github.com/aslamanver/cricket-score-board

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Nothing on the page will persist after you close the browser.
You'd need to set a javascript variable equal to the count and save that value somewhere such as Local Storage (See developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Please add a code sample so people can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go. This uses LocalStorage to store the count as a variable, and increments it every time the button is clicked. LocalStorage can only store strings, so to add 1, requires converting to an int first.

I can not embed the code directly in this answer due to SO restrictions. Here is the code and a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLyva5oq/).

**HTML:**

```
<button class='clickButton' onclick="clickButtonFunction()">Click to increment</button>

<div id='clickCounter'></div>

<button class='clickButton' onclick="clickReset()">Reset count</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
  // This function increases the count
  function clickButtonFunction() {

  console.log('run');

  //Check to see if the localstorage variable exists. If it does not, this is the first time coming to the page, and we need to initalize it to 0
  if (localStorage.getItem("clickCounter") === null) {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("clickCounter", "0");
  }

  // Get the value from local storage
  var value = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clickCounter"));

  // Incrememtnt the count by 1
  var newValue = value + 1

  //Write the value back to local storage
  localStorage.setItem("clickCounter", newValue);


  // Write the value to the div
  document.getElementById("clickCounter").innerHTML = newValue

}

// Reset local storage to 0
function clickReset() {

  localStorage.setItem("clickCounter", "0");
  // Write the value to the div
  document.getElementById("clickCounter").innerHTML = '0'


}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tLyva5oq/

For future, you should really include your attempts at solving the problem, in your question.

Comment: But before  first click  time  count value display 0 and when open window after some time  then before  click    count value display incremented value.

Comment: @AdityaYadav Dude, I got nothing. I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. If you want it to start at 1 or something, then change the default to be 1. If your objecting to the fact the button has to be pressed before the number is shown, just move the display code out from inside of the button press function.

Comment: I ask If your objecting to the fact the button has to be pressed before the number is shown

Comment: but how can we show each user to thier click count @blackandorangecat

Answer (score -1):

you have to save the value of the count in some where like text file time by time and increase it also in file ,so you will not find a problem to know the number of the clicks before you close the browser , you can find it in your text file.